# Query executes on phpmyadmin, but not in python script

Tags: python, mysql

The statement is set-up so that when a record already exists, it doesn't add a record, else, it does.

I've tried changing the query, even though I don't see anything wrong with it.
I've let the script run on python, and print the query it executed. Then I pasted that query in phpmyadmin, where it executed succesfully.
I have also double checked all parameters.

Query (blank params):

```
INSERT INTO users (uname,pass) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '{}','{}') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT uname FROM users WHERE uname = '{}') LIMIT 1;
```

Query (filled in parameters):

```
INSERT INTO users (uname,pass) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'john_doe','password') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT uname FROM users WHERE uname = 'john_doe') LIMIT 1;
```

Python script (the important part)

```
    if action == "add_user":
        username = form.getvalue('username')
        password = form.getvalue('password')
        query = """
        INSERT INTO users (uname,pass) SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT '{}','{}') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT uname FROM users WHERE uname = '{}') LIMIT 1;
        """.format(username, password, username)
        mycursor.execute(query)
```

I know a couple of things.

1. There is nothing wrong with the database connection.
2. The parameters are not empty (ex. username="john_doe" & password="secret")
3. The query actually executes in that specific table.
4. The query seems to add a record and delete it directly afterwards (as AUTO_INCREMENT increases each time, even when the python script executes and doesn't add anything)
5. A try except doesn't do anything, as mysql.connector.Error doesn't report any error (which is obvious, since the query actually executes succesfully)

phpMyAdmin practical example:
(Removed INSERT INTO part in order to be able to show the resulting tables)

The first time you enter the query (above query as example), it will result in  a table with both values as both column names as column values.
Screenshot of table output: http://prntscr.com/nkgaka

Once that result is entered once, next time you will try to insert it, it will simply result in only column names, no values. This means it will insert nothing, as there is nothing to insert as there are no actual values.
Screenshot of table output: http://prntscr.com/nkgbp3

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In most Python DB-APIs, you need to `conn.commit()` after action queries to complete transaction unless you include `autocommit` in connection object. Many new Python users forget to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ensure any field is unique in a table, make that field a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE KEY`. In this case you want `name` to be unique.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name ON users(name)
```

With this in place you only need to `INSERT`. If a duplicate key error occurs the name already exists.

To avoid SQL injection, don't use `"""SELECT {}""".format`. It will be SQL injection vulnerable.

Also don't store plain text passwords, ever. Salted hashes at least. There's plenty of frameworks that do this well already so you don't need to invent your own.